# Order groups in a stacked stripchart by sum in R

Tags: r, stripchart

I have a grouped and stacked `stripchart()` in `R`.

```
stripchart(gear ~ cyl, data=mtcars, method="stack")
```

[image]

`cyl` are the groups here. I want to groups ordered by its sum. From bottom to top the ordering should be 6, 4 and 8.

How can I do this automaticly in a `stripchart`?

Comment: Have you tried making `cyl` a factor with the order of the levels determined by the group sum?

Comment: @Jota Sounds intereseting and R-like. But I don't know how to order factors by any condition (e.g. `sum`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentiont from Jota and with detailed help from [How to order factors by condition in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42461697/how-to-order-factors-by-condition-in-r)

Transforming `cyl` into `factor` and order it's levels.

```
mtcars$cyl <- factor(mtcars$cyl, levels=names(sort(table(mtcars$cyl))))
```