# How to order factors by condition in R?

Tags: r

I want to order factors depending on the sum of the observations.

```
df <- mtcars[,c('cyl', 'gear')]
df$cyl <- factor(df$cyl)

str(df)
'data.frame':   32 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ cyl : Factor w/ 3 levels "4","6","8": 2 2 1 2 3 2 3 1 1 2 ...
 $ gear: num  4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
```

Please see the sum `cyl` in the rows.

```
addmargins(table(df))
     gear
cyl    3  4  5 Sum
  4    1  8  2  11
  6    2  4  1   7
  8   12  0  2  14
  Sum 15 12  5  32
```

Ascending the ordering of `cyl` should be `6`, `4` and `8`. I mean

```
 $ cyl : Factor w/ 3 levels "6","4","8"
```

How can I realize that?

The background of the question is:
[Order groups in a stacked stripchart by sum in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42426970/order-groups-in-a-stacked-stripchart-by-sum-in-r).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can feed the desired ordering into the levels argument of `factor`. In this case, to do it on the fly, replace your second line with:

```
df$cyl <- factor(df$cyl, levels=names(sort(table(df$cyl))))
```

Then you get

```
str(df)
'data.frame':   32 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ cyl : Factor w/ 3 levels "6","4","8": 1 1 2 1 3 1 3 2 2 1 ...
 $ gear: num  4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
```

Here, the frequency values are calculated using `table` and then sorted in ascending order using `sort`. The result is fed to the levels argument which determines the ordering of the levels in `factor`.

Note: I originally wrapped `names` in `as.numeric`, but then found this is not necessary. The `factor` function performs the necessary conversion.